# How can a Groovy closure curry itself for repetition?

Tags: groovy, closures

I'm implementing Groovy step definitions for Cucumber-JVM and I want a step to be able store itself so that the next step can repeat it n times.

```
Given(~'the (\\S+) is in the blender') { String thing ->
    // do stuff...
    context.repeatable = self.curry(thing)
}
```

What should "self" be in the above code?

I can't use "this" as that refers to the enclosing object (whatever that is in this case, maybe the script).

Comment: You need a reference to the method it is in?

Comment: No, a reference to the closure itself, from inside the closure.

Comment: I believe 'this' used to be that reference to itself but 'this' was changed at some point to be a reference to an instance of the class in which the closure is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `curry` is a method of the [Closure](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html) class, directly invoking curry applies to the closure, both if it is named:

```
def context

test = { String thing ->
    context = curry(thing)
    thing.toUpperCase() 
}

test('hello')
println context.call()
test('world')
println context.call()
```

=>

```
HELLO
WORLD
```

or anonymous:

```
def context

['test'].each { String thing ->
    context = curry(thing)
    thing.toUpperCase() 
}

println context.call()
```

=>

```
TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using unreferenced `curry` method passing the received parameters:

```
clos = { String text ->
    if (text) {
        println "text=$text"
        a = curry null
        a()
    } else {
        println "done"
    }
}

clos "closure text"
```

Will print:

```
text=closure text
done
```

---

**Update**

You can also use `clone()`:

```
closure = {
    def clone = clone()
}
```